# Which is correct? Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

[image]

Unfortunately I noticed that all are wrong.

(A) Counterexample: $G=(1)$

(B), (C), (D) Counterexample: $G=\{1,-1\}$

Please help! Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Any finite multiplicative subgroup of $\Bbb C^\ast $ must be of roots of unity. What do you know about those?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: their product is 1?

Comment: $\{1,-1\}$ are $2^{nd}$ roots of unity... But then $1.(-1)\neq 1$... do you see what is wrong with this???

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik What is your point?

Comment: I was trying to make it clear before you write your statement "IF the order is different from $2$, Yes".. That is what i have tried he OP to be clear about the case...

Comment: @PeterTamaroff If $|G|=4$ (or any even number) then (D) is also false.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen My bad. The product is $\exp((n-1)i \pi)$, yes? So $+1$ for odds, $-1$ for evens.

Comment: I am following up the comment of @PeterTamaroff, i.e., your $G$ is the set of $n$-th roots of unity for some $n$. There is a quick way to see what the sum of the elements of $G$ is. The elements of $G$ are the roots of $x^{n} -1$. Their sum is thus the negative of the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$, so $1$ if $n = 1$, and $0$ if $n > 1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, and the question is wrong. (And you did not need to ask here to be sure; your counterexamples are convincing).

If it were your task to correct the question (and unfortunately readers of mathematical texts often find themselves in the uncomfortable position of having to correct apparent errors in what they are reading, and guessing the most probable oversight of the author) then you can choose from the additional hypotheses "$|G|>1$" (or $G$ is nontrivial) which makes (A) true, or "$2\nmid|G|$" (or $G$ is of odd order) which makes (D) true.

The first correction seems the most likely one. However it requires (very elementary) ring theory, not just group theory. If $G$ is a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field (or domain) and $a\in G\setminus\{1\}$ then $a\sum_{g\in G} g=\sum_{g\in G}ag=\sum_{g\in G}g$ so $(a-1)\sum_{g\in G}g=0$ and since $a-1\neq0$ one has $\sum_{g\in G}g=0$.

If instead one adds the hypothesis $|G|$ is odd, then $\prod_{g\in G}g=1$. This follows from simple group theory and the fact that $G$ is Abelian (without which the product would make no sense). One can pair up mutually inverse elements in the product, which pairs contribute nothing, leaving only the involutions ($g^2=1$) single, so $\prod_{g\in G}g$ gives the same group restricted to the involutions only. In a group of odd order the identity is the only involution. (When instead $|G|$ is taken even then $\prod_{g\in G}g=-1$, since $-1$ is the unique element of order$~2$ in $G$, and even in $\Bbb C^*$.)

*Added.* The argument given for (A) with the assumption $|G|>1$ does not use commutativity of multiplication, so it holds for instance for finite subgroups of a skew field (a.k.a. division ring), which do not have to be cyclic. However, it does use the absence of zero divisors, and one might wonder if this can be avoided. The answer is it cannot, as the property sometimes fails in rings with zero divisors: the sum of both invertible elements in $\Bbb F_2[X]/(X^2)$ is $X$ rather than $0$.

Comment: So the answer is no to all of (A), (B), (C), (D). How does that make the question wrong?

Comment: @DerekHolt It is formatted like a multiple choice question; the implicit assumption then is that one and only one answer should be correct. Adding "(E) No single one of the above must always hold" would be another way to correct the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right. So the problem should be modified that $G$ be a nontrivial finite subgroup, in which case any element $g\in G$ has the form
$$g=e^{i\theta}$$
where $\theta$ is rational. Thus the answer is, all add up to 0.

Comment: A very nice proof of that fact: multiply the sum by any non-trivial  group element, and it remains the same...